# The tags [multi-platform] and [multiplatform] should be merged

Tags: discussion, tags

As of October 9, [multi-platform](/questions/tagged/multi-platform) is used on
42 questions, [multiplatform](/questions/tagged/multiplatform) on 72 questions.
It would be helpful to use a consistent form for
these tags, since both have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

How should these relate to [cross-platform](/questions/tagged/cross-platform) (1463) and [crossplatform](/questions/tagged/crossplatform) (0)?

Maybe just synonym them all to [cross-platform](/questions/tagged/cross-platform) as it is leading the usage stakes by a considerable margin?

Comment: Maybe.  I am not willing to say what the best approach should be here.  I would appreciate more opinions.

Comment: I've been sitting here trying to convince myself that there is a clear semantic difference between multi- and cross-, but I'm not having a lot of luck. If someone else can think of a convincing distinction I'll withdraw the suggestion.

Comment: I don't think any of them add any value as tags.